# For a monad: what is the $\mu: T^2 \rightarrow T$ natural transformation?

Tags: category-theory

Wikipedia says that a Monad has a natural transformation:

$$\mu: T^2 \rightarrow T$$

Where:

$C$ is a category, and  $T$ is an endofunctor: $T: C \rightarrow C$

$T^2$ is a functor $T \circ T$ from $C$ to $C$.

I'm trying to understand $\mu$ and $T^2$.  What do these definitions mean?

(I'm a programmer trying to understand just enough category theory for a particular problem.)

Comment: It's just a natural transformation, which together with another  $\eta:1_C\to T$ satisfies a bunch of axioms.

Comment: What does it mean when it says $T^2$ is a functor $T \circ T$ from C to C?  And what does $T^2 \rightarrow T$ mean -- it's transforming a functor into a particular endofunctor T?  But the functor it's transforming is just T composed with itself?  (As you can tell I'm in a bit over my head.)

Comment: The composition of a functor with a functor is a functor.

Comment: Does T mean "any endofunctor for category C" or is it one particular functor?

Comment: Is it saying any two endofunctors of category C compose into an endofunctor?  Or is $\mu$ a particular natural transformation that makes two composed endofunctors of C also an endofunctor?  (Am I right in thinking we're talking about endofunctors at all, or are some of these just functors?  It said $T^2$ went from C to C, so I figured that made it an endofunctor.)

Answer (score 6):

Every monad is defined as the following data $\def\C{\mathcal C}(\C, T,\mu,\eta)$ where
- $\C$ is a category 
-  $T$ is an endofunctor $T:\C\to\C$ 
- $\mu$ is a natural transformation $T\circ T\to T$, 
$\quad\quad$ i.e. it is a collection of arrows $\mu_c:T(Tc)\to Tc$ for $c\in Ob\,\C$, satisfying a commutativity condition 
- $\eta$ is a natural transformation $1_\C\to T$, 
$\quad\quad$ i.e. a collection of arrows $c\to Tc$.

(And these data has to satisfy some *monoid-like* axioms: 'associativity' of $\mu$ - yielding a unique extension of the 'operation' $\mu$ to $T^3\to T$, and left and right 'identity' axioms for $\eta$.)

---

Best is to understand with specific examples.

In the case of (a variant of) the *list monad*, we have 
- $\C=\mathcal Set$ 
- $T:A\mapsto A^*$ where $A^*$ is the set of finite lists (or 'words') of elements of $A$, $\ T(A)=A^*=\bigsqcup_{n\in\Bbb N}A^n$ 
- $T^2(A)=\{\langle w_1,w_2,\dots,w_n\rangle\,:\,n\in\Bbb N, w_i\in A^*\}$, i.e. its elements are 'sentences' of words, when letters taken from $A$ 
- $\mu_A:T^2(A)\to T(A)$ is the *concatenation* of words: $\langle w_1,\dots,w_n\rangle\mapsto w_1\cdots w_n$ 
- $\eta_A:A\to T(A)$ picks the one-element words for the letters

Note that $A^*$ is the 'free semigroup' (or 'free monoid' if the empty word is included in the above) generated by $A$, and so that the list monad is also called the 'free semigroup monad'.

---

The *free commutative ring monad* consists of: 
- $\C=\mathcal Set$ 
- $T(A):=\Bbb Z[A]$ the set of all polynomials with integer coefficients and variables taken from $A\ $ 
$\quad\quad$ [e.g. the expression $2ab-73c^2\,\in T(\{a,b,c,d\})$]. 
- Elements of $T^2(A)$ can be thought of as *parenthesized* expressions 
- $\mu$ opens up the brackets 
- $\eta$ assigns the single variable polynomial to a single variable.